# Signing office COM Add-in

Tags: c#, ms-office, class-library, comaddin, netoffice

I've developed an extension based on NetOffice. My office configuration requires applications to be signed by Trusted Publishers. I tried signing the output DLL with signtool.exe, with a valid certificate, but unfortunately, Office says "There is no digital signature available".

The option can be enabled via:

> File → Options → Trust Center → Trust Center Settings → Add-ins → Require application Add-ins to be signed by Trusted Publisher

What's the appropriate method for signing the DLL?

When using VSTO, ClickOnce handles the signing, also there's a .manifest file that is created for the DLL, I'm not sure if its required or not but I'm unable to create one for my class library.

Some info that I found online:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772096(v=vs.120).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/che5h906.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First, create a .pfx file with pvk2pfx.exe:

- "C:{PATH}\pvk2pfx.exe" -pvk {PVK FILE NAME} -pi {cert owner name} -spc {SPC FILE NAME} -pfx {PFX FILE NAME}
- e.g.: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\pvk2pfx.exe" -pvk mypvkfile.pvk -pi **companyname** -spc **myspcfile**.spc -pfx **mypfxfile**.pfx

Then use the SignTool.exe utility:

- signtool sign /f "C:{PATH}\mypfxfile.pfx" /p {cert owner name} "C:{PATH}\setup.exe"

Comment: This is the way I'm signing it. I use this on all DLLs and Exe files and then sign the setup as well.

Comment: So it's apparently signed properly but Office is still complaining that it's not signed?

Comment: Yep. Thing is, I got another addin which is native C++ with COM and ATL - it works as expected. 
But using exactly the same steps for the Managed addin, doesn't work :(
I saw Add-in Express are somehow able to sign a managed addin properly. Unfortunately, I didn't get the chance to figure out what is the difference.

Comment: Something is weird here but I admit that I oddly never seem to encounter the Trusted Publishers list - and I've built dozens of add-ins.  Give me a bit and I'll refresh my understanding of the mechanics of it and hopefully I can help.